# How to merge two WordPress databases with the same structure?

Tags: database, merging

I have two WordPress sites with the same database structure (same prefix, number of tables etc.).

Now I want to merge all data from the two databases to make it one single database. How can I do that?

Comment: Working with the database tables directly is a bad idea. Recommend using a WP importer to properly add the new content from site 2 to site 1.

Comment: Thanks. I have used that solution. But not working correctly with my case.

Comment: Hi @ThuLinhNguyen: welcome to WPSE. Your question can be seen from 2 different perspectives: **(1)** it's a generic database merge question, in which we'll have to consider all possible scenarios, e.g. different themes, plugins, page builders etc. This is **too broad** & hence **not answerable** in the format supported here. **(2)** it is very specific to your case, which is not useful for others & may require access to your database to solve properly. This is also **not answerable** here, as it is **too localized**. So best if you employ an expert to do the job for you.

Comment: There is a new plugin : **Versionpress** https://stackoverflow.com/a/55243047/4217721